Returning a value from AJAX inside a jQuery Plugin
I have this small plugin. How do I update the value of exists and return it to the element that called the plugin?
$.fn.doesEmailExist = function() {
    let email = $(this).val();
    var exists = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_url + "user/doesEmailExistAjax",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'email': email },
        success : function(response) {           
                
        }, error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
            var message = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText + ' - ' + exception;
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}

I tried return = $.ajax({ }); and tried using a promise, but it didn't seem to work.
Called with:
if (element.doesEmailExist() == true) {}

Can you please share you're attempt with the promise?

@nick I don't really know how, that is why I am asking... how would I do this with a callback function and no plugin, just a straight JavaScript function?

Google isn't giving me much luck.

You'd use either promises or callbacks, take a look at that link I sent, it explains how it can be done. The idea is though, you won't be able to do  if (element.doesEmailExist() == true) {} because doesEmailExist() is asynchronous, so it doesn't return immediately. If you use a regular callback, you can change your doesEmailExist() to accept a function (a callback argument, fn), then in your success function call your argument fn(response). In your calling code, you'd pass a callback to your function  doesEmailExist(function(response) { if(response.exists) // logic })
